# Multiple values in EMR Cluster Configuration template

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

Within my EMR module I have a template that is deployed for the cluster configuration, within this template are all the cluster configuration requirements for the given classification type as specified in the variable emr_cluster_applications e.g. Spark, Hadoop, Hive.

Visual:

```
emr_cluster_applications = ["Spark", "Hadoop", "Hive"]
emr_cluster_configurations = file("./filepath/to/template.json")
```

This set up works fine however moving forward I'm wondering if the template can be populated based on the values within the emr_cluster_applications variable.

For example in a seperate deployment, if ["Spark", "Hadoop"] were specified as opposed to all three, then the template file would only use the corresponding Spark and Hadoop configuration with Hive being ignored although still present in the file - is this possible?

Update:
Template file:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark",
    "Properties":{
       "maximizeResourceAllocation": "false",
       "spark.executor.memoryOverhead": "4G"
     }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "hive",
    "Properties":{
      "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": XXXX
      "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName": XXXX
      "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName": XXXX
      "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword": XXXX
     }
  },
  {
     "Classification": "hbase-site",
     "Properties": {
        "hbase.rootdir": "XXXXXXXXXX"
      }
  },
  {
     "Classification": "hbase",
     "Properties":{
        "hbase.emr.storageMode": "s3"
        "hbase.emr.readreplica.emnabled": "true"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Are these values assigned within the root module or you are assigning those values in the child module?

Comment: At current moment within root module

Comment: Ah, ok, so based on the `emr_cluster_applications` list you want to make changes to the template file in the `emr_cluster_configuration`?

Comment: If that is the case, you could use `templatefile`, but I would have to see the template file as well as where the change would need to happen.

Comment: 1) - yes thats correct
2) - the template file is quite large and I won't have enough characters to paste though in essence not to far from what i've found in an example here: https://github.com/SebastianUA/terraform-aws-emr/blob/master/examples/additional_files/emr-cluster-configurations_json.json

Comment: You can add the template file to the question and not to the comment. :) It would also be helpful to mark the values you would need being populated by the `emr_cluster_applications`. :)

Comment: Would the `Properties` for different `Classifications` remain the same? If that is the case then I can maybe think of a way to do what you want.

Comment: When would `hbase` and `hbase-site` be added? When the application is Hadoop?

Comment: That’s correct, yes.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could come up with and there might be better solutions, so take this with a grain of salt. I have problems with mapping the Hadoop to two different elements from the JSON, so I had to do some modifications to the variables in order to make it work. I strongly suggest doing any variable manipulation within a `locals` block in order to avoid clutter in the resources. The `locals.tf` example:

```
locals {

  emr_template = [
    {
      "Classification" : "spark",
      "Properties" : {
        "maximizeResourceAllocation" : "false",
        "spark.executor.memoryOverhead" : "4G"
      }
    },
    {
      "Classification" : "hive",
      "Properties" : {
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" : "XXXX",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" : "XXXX",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" : "XXXX",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" : "XXXX"
      }
    },
    {
      "Classification" : "hbase-site",
      "Properties" : {
        "hbase.rootdir" : "XXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    },
    {
      "Classification" : "hbase",
      "Properties" : {
        "hbase.emr.storageMode" : "s3",
        "hbase.emr.readreplica.emnabled" : "true"
      }
    }
  ]

  emr_template_mapping = { for template in local.emr_template : template.Classification => template }
  
  hadoop_enabled           = false
  hadoop                   = local.hadoop_enabled ? ["hbase", "hbase-site"] : []
  apps_enabled             = ["spark", "hive"]
  emr_cluster_applications = concat(local.apps_enabled, local.hadoop)

}
```

You can manipulate which apps will be added with two options:

1. If the Hadoop is enabled, that means `hbase` and `hbase-site` need to be added to the list of the allowed apps. If it is not enabled, then the value of the `hadoop` variable will be an empty list.
2. In the `apps_enabled` local variable you decide which ones you want to enable, i.e., `spark`, `hive`, none, or both.

Finally, in the `emr_cluster_applications` local variable you would use `concat` to concatenate the two lists into one.

Then, to create a JSON file locally, you could use the `local_file` option:

```
resource "local_file" "emr_template_file" {
  content = jsonencode([for app in local.emr_cluster_applications :
    local.emr_template_mapping["${app}"] if contains(keys(local.emr_template_mapping), "${app}")
    ]
  )
  filename = "${path.root}/template.json"
}
```

The `local_file` will output a JSON encoded file which can be used where you need it. I am pretty sure there are better ways to do it, so maybe someone else will see this and give a better answer.